# using 2 web-cams simultaniuously in openCv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

currently I have three web-cams connected to my laptop, the internal webcam and a two same company's external web-cam. I want to take input from the external web-cams for a single object simultaniously.

I am not very sure what should i do for that.Should I do

```
    CvCapture* capture1=cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
    CvCapture* capture2=cvCaptureFromCAM(2);
```

I mean should i take input from CAM(1) and CAM(2) as I don't want to take input from the internal camera of the laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a simple test that captures only from one camera. Then change the index number passed to `cvCaptureFromCAM()` until you can identify which indexes correspond to the webcams you are interested at.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194673/176769) is a must read since it provides very interesting information related to this task, and [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/149674/two-webcams-with-opencv) shares some code.

Comment: dear Karlphillip  can you tell me you can I count the number of cameras? I tried using cvcamGetCamerasCount function but opencv2.2 can't recognize it. thanks

Comment: The latest OpenCV version is 2.3.1, I suggest you update to it and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much I used cvCaptureFromCAM and identify which indexes correspond to the webcam as you said...it was reaally helpful thank you...I want to ask you some thing very different..how can I find the co-ordinate of matched keypoints in image1 and image2 both...thanks

Comment: I have asked in new treat here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345832/co-ordinate-of-the-matched-sift-keypoints/10347081#10347081