# Python OpenCV stereo cam blind one?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, real-time

My system is Linux HPDebian 3.2.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux Python 2.7, OpenCV2. I can use only 1 cam.

My question is How to get a video feed from 2 cams? I had read C++ version but I prefer python. It is easier for non-programmer.

I don't understand why my webcam works only Wleft, but WRight is blank-gray windows. And at the command line

> VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument

continue to flood my command line.

OpenCV-Python has a ready-made package of stereo program, but I need to access the elements of each cam because I want to test my algorithm.

My attempt:

```
'''
Simple Stereo feed
'''
import cv
cv.NamedWindow("wLeft", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv.NamedWindow("wRight", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
captureL = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
captureR = cv.CaptureFromCAM(1)

def repeat():
    frameL = cv.QueryFrame(captureL)
    cv.ShowImage("wLeft", frameL)
    frameR = cv.QueryFrame(captureR)
    cv.ShowImage("wRight", frameR)

while True:
    repeat()
    if cv.WaitKey(33)==27:
       break

cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

### Update 1

Answer to your questions:

1. In current OpenCV-Python. I can not find any command, but I when I comment out the Leftcam, Rightcam works. And vice versa.
2. Yes, I just found it!. I redirected command and carefully searched.

   > libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
3. They are identical. OKER193.
4. I can use it just only 1 cam Left or Right only. Can not get a video feed from two of them simulataneously.
5. I have no hubs. I don't know it is a real port or not, but I connect it left and right of my notebook.

   http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Multiple-Camera-Read-Error-td7001563.html

I tried cv.ReleaseCapture()

```
def repeat():
        frameL = cv.QueryFrame(captureL)
        cv.ShowImage("wLeft", frameL)
        cv.ReleaseCapture(captureL)
        frameR = cv.QueryFrame(captureR)
        cv.ShowImage("wRight", frameR)
        cv.ReleaseCapture(captureR)
```

I got the errors:

```
...
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument //Many lines
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "55.py", line 19, in <module>
    repeat()
  File "55.py", line 13, in repeat
    cv.ReleaseCapture(captureL)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ReleaseCapture'
```

I really wonder

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=releasecapture
CaptureFromCAM last line say To release the structure, use ReleaseCapture. This function may be dropped out.

Wandering around and found this

https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux

Then I check my resolution per cam is 640x480 as a normal. And my webcam is 1.1/2.0 USB interface.

```
root@HPDebian:~# v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
```

Then check another cam

```
root@HPDebian:~# v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
```

At this point I am not sure about my USB notebook. It may be a hub inside. I will try reduce the resolution and post my result again.

### Update 2

Try time.sleep(1) from Martin:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument //Many lines
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT

libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device
VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument  //Many lines until Ctrl C
```

I will try this again in M$ xp.

### Update 3

Still using Linux. M$ xp is busy. This time I del the c1 and c2. Since I don't know how to release camera. I believe that API of driver I use is allow only 1 device access kernel per time. So I try this one.

```
def repeat1():
    c1 = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
    i1 = cv.QueryFrame(c1)
    cv.ShowImage("WebCAM1", i1)
    del(c1)
def repeat2():
    c2 = cv.CreateCameraCapture(1)
    i2 = cv.QueryFrame(c2)
    cv.ShowImage("WebCAM2", i2)    
    del(c2)
```

Program run very sluggish and WebCAM1 is distorted, WebCAM2 is not.

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one experiencing this: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv.user/263

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV with 2 cameras VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194033/opencv-with-2-cameras-vc)

Comment: Have you tried "import cv2" and "CaputureL = video.create_capture(0)"? Also you should probably release your cameras at the break with "CaputureL.release()" as this could lead to problems while debugging.

Comment: @Snesticle: Good point on importing the library twice - it could be sharing some resources in there...

Comment: @Snesticle I am now reading the command cv2 sir.

Comment: @Snesticle I had tried import cv2 for another cam. It can run only 1 and re turn this 

libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
VIDIOC_STREAMON: No space left on device

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Is OpenCV picking up all your cameras? Try [checking how many cameras are attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322939/how-to-count-cameras-in-opencv-2-3).
2. Do you get any error other error messages? i.e. is there a stack track with the one you've mentioned?
3. Are there any hardware differences between the two cameras?
4. What happens if you comment out all the stuff about lcam? i.e. is it just something to do with the second camera or is it something to do with running two cameras at once.
5. Try plugging them into seperate hubs as per [this suggestion](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=m5l5gsjssc5pv0jimj4nbsvst2&/topic,8179.0.html)

Comment: A Sleep() between the two camera setups is sometime necessary - at least on Windows with poor USB webcam drivers

Comment: @Martin Sleep() function. Ok I will try your advice.

Comment: @MartinBeckett I updated the answer, still can not solve this.

Comment: @Sarit - can the web cams do MJPG? Two streams of raw YUYV (even at 300kpixels) might be too much for a single USB hub

Comment: @MartinBeckett I don't know. And how do I know that ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a general multi-camera issue, I was able to resolve it by using a gsteamer pipeline. With kernel 4.15.0-34-generic on Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenCV 3.4 compiled with gstreamer/v4l support I am able to stream 3x720p on a single USB port using a powered hub using MJPG compression with gstreamer in python (using 2xC922 and 1xC920 cameras - the 10fps framerate isn't necessary for this to work):

```
def open_cam_usb(dev, width, height):
    gst_str = (
        "v4l2src device=/dev/video{} ! "
        "image/jpeg,widh=(int){},height=(int){},framerate=10/1,"
        "format=(string)RGB ! "
        "jpegdec ! videoconvert ! appsink"
    ).format(dev, width, height)
    return cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am sorry it is 6 years by now. I could not be able to verify your answer.

Comment: That's fine, it's more for future people who come across here.